# Simple condition that returns true if document.activeElement = ""

Tags: javascript

I need to know if the selected element has an ID.

What am I doing wrong?

```
  var selected = document.activeElement;
  if (selected.id = "") {
  document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML= "is blank";    
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you can't test equality with `=`.  It requires `==` (identity with type conversion) or `===` (identity without any type conversion).

In any case, it's a bit safer to do the comparison this way:

```
var selected = document.activeElement;
if (selected && selected.id) {
  document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML= "is blank";    
}
```

`if (selected.id)` will be true if either `selected.id == null` or `selected.id == undefined` or `selected.id == ""` which will cover more cases than just `if (selected.id == "")`.

Comment: [document.activeElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#dom-document-activeelement) (if suppoerted) must return either the currently active (focused) element, or the body element. Accessing the DOM element [id](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-63534901) property must return a string, therefore a conforming browser will never return *null* and will only ever return a string, which will be the value of the element's *id* or an empty string.

Comment: I still maintain that `if (selected.id)` is better general programming practice.

Comment: According to MS, IE could return null for document.activeElement: "A value of null is given for this property, if it is accessed inline during the loading of a document." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533065.aspx.

Plus, jfriend00's principle is a sound one -- just because today it is *conforming browser* behavior that document.activeElement should never return null, it doesn't mean that in the future such browsers will hold fast to this rule.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the id instead of comparing it. Change `=` to `==`.

```
var selected = document.activeElement;
if (selected.id == "") {
  document.getElementById('test3').innerHTML= "is blank";    
}
```